# Pie Chart Not Popping Up HighCharts

Tags: javascript, pandas, highcharts, pie-chart, justpy

I am trying to make a pie chart that shows that rating of a python course. However every time I try to run it, the pie chart doesn't pop up, only the title. I am using HighCharts to create the pie chart and it is also supposed to be interactive. This is what I am using to create the pie chart. I also don't get any error message. Please help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic

This is my code down below:

```
import justpy as jp
import justpy as jp
import pandas as pa
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import utc 

data = pa.read_csv("reviews.csv", parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
share = data.groupby(['Course Name'])['Rating'].count()


chart_def = """ 
 {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
}
"""
def app(): 
    wp = jp.QuasarPage()
    h1 = jp.QDiv(a = wp, text = "Analaysis of Course Reviews", classes='text-h3 text-center q-pa-md')
    p1 = jp.QDiv(a = wp, text = "These graphs represent course review analaysis")

    hc = jp.HighCharts(a= wp, options = chart_def)
    hc_data = [{"name":v1, "y":v2} for v1, v2 in zip(share.index, share)]
    hc.options.series[0].data = hc_data
    
    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

Comment: Hi @EpicNinja, The structure of chart options looks ok, but the empty chart might indicate a problem with data. Could you try to run some other series with simple data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by removing (or commenting out) the 2 code lines below, which set the "***plotBackgroundColor***" and "***plotBorderWidth***" properties to null:

```
chart_def = """ 
 {
    chart: {
        //plotBackgroundColor: null,  --> remove or comment out this line
        //plotBorderWidth: null, --> remove or comment out this line
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
```

(...)